# How to extend LVM size

Tags: lvm

I have additional free space on my sda disk and I want to add this space to my LVM. How can I add this 2.5T space to my LVM without destroying the existing partition or losing any data?

sda                    8:0    0  2.5T  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                 8:2    0    2G  0 part    /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0   98G  0 part
└─ubuntu--vg-lv--0 253:0    0   98G  0 lvm  /

```
vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <98.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25087
  Alloc PE / Size       25087 / <98.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               TuH50U-jINw-l4IH-vuos-1sSt-xrO4-1c7C5Z
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running parted and creating a new partition by mkpart primary.